# Generar modelo para el response de una api

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, api

Al momento de consumir una api me retorna el siguiente response.

```
[
    {
         "MiKey": 0000,
         "MiKey": 02,
         "MiKey": "CADENA",
    }
]
```

*Datos ficticios*

Mi Modelo:

```
public class RootObject
{
    public int MiKey { get; set; }
    public int MiKey { get; set; }
    public string MiKey { get; set; }
}
```

*Datos ficticios*

Pero al momento de hacer el await con este modelo me devuelve el siguiente error.

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'DetamaticWeb.Models.RootOb' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.
>   To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.
>   Path '', line 1, position 1.

Cual seria el modelo a generar correctamente? Ya que por lo que veo el modelo o la salida de datos es la que esta dando el problema.

Comment: El api te esta retornando un arreglo de objetos, por eso los corchetes []. No puedes serializar un arreglo de objetos en tu modelo, prueba con una lista de objetos. List<RootObject>

Comment: Cual es el tipo de lista que estas utilizando para devolver los datos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El IDE de Visual Studio tiene una función de dado un `Json` generar clases de C#. Selecciona el `Json`, cópialo al portapapeles y ve al menú `Edit\Paste special\Paste JSON as classes`. Lo pongo en inglés porque así lo tengo configurado. Esto nos proporciona un modelo así

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public Class1[] Property1 { get; set; }
}

public class Class1
{
    public string MiKey { get; set; }
}
```

Todo es un `string` ya que tanto `0000` como `02`no son valores numéricos como un entero.

Comment: Perfecto ! gracias,